# Convert a unicode string for a webservice - equivalent to php utf8_encode in Android

Tags: android, http, utf-8, character-encoding

My Android app needs to connect to a webservice that will decode a unicode string using [utf8_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php). How can I encode my string in my application in a similar way as php [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)?

I have found [CharsetEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) but am not sure how to use it.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using just the String class, but just a note about converting text to/from UTF and ISO. When decoding from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 will cause "replacement characters" (�) to appear in your text when unsupported characters are found.

To encode texts:

```
byte[] utf8 = new String(latin1, "ISO-8859-1").getBytes("UTF-8");
```

or

```
byte[] latin1 = new String(utf8, "UTF-8").getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```